# Pythone error: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-translate'

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I build a google translate application and it was running fine in pycharm. When I converted the files into single executable file using pyinstaller the executable file is not running. I have imported `from google.cloud import translate_v2`

Error message is noted below:

**pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-translate' distribution was not found and is required by the application**

Please help where went wrong.Let me know if any other details required

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to the command line when running pyinstaller:

`--copy-metadata google-cloud-translate`

But actually, if you use a newer PyInstaller version, the automatic bytecode [scanning should do that](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/5830) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have solved the issue by editing the code in the below path

**C:\Users\3888123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\google\cloud\translate_v2_init_.py**

**From**

```
from pkg_resources import get_distribution
__version__ = get_distribution("google-cloud-translate").version
from google.cloud.translate_v2.client import Client
__all__ = ("__version__", "Client")
```

**To**

```
__version__ = "4"
from google.cloud.translate_v2.client import Client
__all__ = ("__version__", "Client")
```

**Result**

Single executable file created with out error. Hope this answer helps some one.